# https остается красным

Tags: nginx, https, ssl

Добрый вечер. настраиваю ssl сертификат для своего сайта. Получил бесплатный DV серт от StartSSL. После всех настроек в nginx в браузере https продолжает подсвечиваться красным. Тесты на ssllabs дают оценку А.

nginx 1.10.0

[ссылка на тест ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=yoom.team)

конфиг nginx

```
server {

    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl;

    root /var/www/html/yoom.team/web/;
    index app_dev.php;
    server_name 176.112.223.254 yoom.team www.yoom.team;

    access_log /var/log/yoom.team/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/yoom.team/error.log;

    keepalive_timeout   60;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/yoom.team/yoom.team.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/yoom.team/private.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers  "HIGH:!RC4:!aNULL:!MD5:!kEDH";
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=604800';

    location / {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ / break;
    }

    location ~ ^/(.*).(js|css|png|jpeg|jpg|html) {
        root /var/www/html/yoom.team/web/;
    }

    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        try_files $uri /app_dev.php$is_args$args;
                fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_index app_dev.php;
                include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    }


}

upstream php-fpm {
    server unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема не в конфигурации, многие браузеры прекратили поддержку этого центра выдачи сертификатов. Сертификатам StartSSL больше не доверяют браузеры Firefox, Chrome и другие. Конечно, он продолжает выдавать сертификаты, но к сожалению сертификаты не принимаются известными браузерами.

Столь кардинальные меры в отношении удостоверяющих центров WoSign и StartCom приняты после выявления многочисленных нарушений. После того как для алгоритма SHA-1 был выявлен ускоренный метод подбора коллизий, в регламентирующие деятельность удостоверяющих центров документы были внесены изменения, предписывающие с 1 января 2016 года полностью прекратить использование SHA-1 при создании сертификатов. WoSign и StartCom нарушили данное предписание и продолжили использование SHA-1 для формирования сертификатов, выписывая их задним числом, а также игнорируя требования по окончанию срока действия подобных сертификатов.

> Mozilla and Google decided to distrust all StartCom root certificates
>   as of 21st of October, this situation will have an impact in the
>   upcoming release of Firefox and Chrome in January. StartCom will
>   provide an interim solution soon and will replace all the issued
>   certificates from that date in case of requested. Meanwhile StartCom
>   is updating all their systems and will generate new root CAs as
>   requested by Mozilla to regain the trust in these browsers.

[Ссылка на публикацию](https://www.startssl.com/NewsDetails?date=20161103)

Воспользуйтесь [Letsencrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/), как бесплатной альтернативой для SSL признанной всеми современными браузерами.

Answer (score 0):

Пишу ответом, т.к. пока не могу давать комментарии.

Попробуйте вот такое решение:

Надо данные сертификата (сертификат и секретный ключ) указать в файлах manager.crt (сюда файл сертификата) и manager.key (сюда секретный ключ).
2 этих файла находятся в директории /usr/local/mgr5/etc/

После этого надо перезапустить веб-сервер, я сделал так:
killall ihttpd
service ihttpd start
killall core

Решение не моё, нагуглил тут http://forum.ispsystem.ru/showthread.php?26479&p=162199&viewfull=1#post162199. Так что детальнее не подскажу, может зависеть от ОС, но надеюсь вам поможет.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте версию протокола выставить

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2
```

Или вообще эту строчку убрать